# How to add dynamic row class in ag-Grid table

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I am using ag-grid.com, does anyone know how to add dynamic row class name in the same table? So that I can set different background color base on it.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: This link: [Row Styles](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/) will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found in documentation https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/:

```
var gridOptions = {
    rowData: rowData,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowClassRules: {
        'your-class': function(params) {
            return your_condition;
        }
    }
};
```

and in vuejs it might look like:

```
this.rowClassRules: {
    'your-class': params => {
          return your_condition;
    }
}
```